# How to handle several 'spam like' answers from a specific user?

Tags: discussion, faq, answers, flagging

Apologies if this question has been already asked, I didn't find anything similar to address this specific case.

I've noticed a kind of suspicious behavior lately, with people creating counts and chasing questions where they can spread their 'suggestions' in a spam-like approach.

**Example:**

https://pm.stackexchange.com/users/3274/rigan-disoza?tab=answers

I remember that I noticed a similar case a few days ago.

So, in short:

**What's the best way to handle spam-like answers??**

- Flagging their answers?
- Flagging one of their answers?
- First left a comment - deeply believing in mankind - asking for avoiding this behaviour?

Cheers

Comment: I'm glad you asked this; I've been flagging these these as "needs attention" and have seen the mods do *something* (yay!), but I'm glad to know I wasn't the only one who thought there was something odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you gain more reputation on Project Management SE, you will gain more [privileges](https://pm.stackexchange.com/privileges/) that will help you contribute more to the  community moderation of the site.

The most basic way to help in these situations is to flag the question as spam. Anyone with at least 15 reputation can flag a post.

The moderators on the site will then respond by either leaving a comment on the question/answer, improving it by editing it, closing the question, migrating the question to a more appropriate site, or in the most extreme cases, deleting the question/answer.

As a 1k user, you can flag questions and answers, and you can vote to close a question. It takes five 500+ reputation users to close a question.

You also can edit questions and answers without approval, and you of course can leave comments to help guide users who could improve their questions. I've seen you leave comments on questions that ask the original poster to expand or clarify, and these actions serve as a great signpost to new users and to help make the community more aware about what the Q&A format is about.

In regards to the users who have been spamming the site, if it continues, we do have ways of dealing with this behavior.

Comment: Hi j, that's exactly about the `In regards to the users who have been spamming the site, if it continues, we do have ways of dealing with this behavior` that I'd like to clarify. As of now, I'll flag each 'spam like' post for the same user... hope it helps and does not add overwork on your mod side.

Comment: Not at all. All of the flags I've personally seen have been helpful in some manner, even if they aren't things I've personally taken action on. When we see the spam, Mark and I have been deleting them right away. Thank you for your help.